# Rails Mailer messed up

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I implemented a RoR mailer with my Ruby on Rails Application and it worked well. But to my surprise, every time a mail is sent, *other attributes from my database table is populated in my sent email which I do not want*.

To have a diagramatic view of my problem, **see this Mailer Preview image:**

[image]

**model(job.rb)**

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.jobs_posted_12hrs_ago
    where.not('stripeEmail' => nil).where.not('payola_sale_guid' => nil).where('created_at > ?', Time.now - 12.hours)
  end
end
```

**app/mailer/job_notifier.rb**

```
class JobNotifier < ApplicationMailer


  def send_post_email(job)
    @user = User.where(:email => true).all
    emails = @user.collect(&:email).join("#{';'}")
    @jobs = job
    @job = job
    mail(:to => emails, :bcc => User.pluck(:email).uniq, :subject => 'New job posted on FarFlungJobs')
  end

end
```

**email template/view(send_post_email.html.erb)**

I did iterate over my scope and populated just Comapny Name, Job Title, and Date. but when the email is previewed/sent, other attributes in the database are populated with it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <h3> Hi, new job just posted on FarFlungJobs.com! </h3>
  </div>

  <section>
    <p>Fresh Job</p>
    <hr>
    <p>
      <% jobs = Job.jobs_posted_12hrs_ago %>
        <%= jobs.each do |job| %>
            <section class="container">
              <div class="row jobs">
                <div class="col-md-4" style="font-size: 20px;"><strong><%= job.company_name %></strong></div>
                <div class="col-md-4" style="font-size: 20px;"><%= link_to(job.title, job) %></div>
                <div class="col-md-4 text-right" style="font-size: 20px; float: left;"><%= job.created_at.strftime('%d %B %y') %></div>
              </div>
              <%= render 'shared/two_breaks'%>
            </section>
        <% end %>
    </p>

    <p>Thanks for subscribing to FarFlungJobs once again. <%=  jobs_url %> </p>

  </section>
</body>
</html>
```

> What can I do to make sure I **only** have just the specified attributes in my email template being sent, instead of it add all I dont want?

Comment: What does `shared/two_breaks` have in its content? It seems to be the one outputting that content

Comment: It's has just <br> tag. I used it just to achieve spacing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
<%= jobs.each do |job| %>
```

Because of the <%= it will print out the result of the each statement, which is jobs.

Comment: Yeap, That is the problem. It's completely oversight that am outputting my the whole of my db which was not necessary.